# Javascript Difference of any number

Tags: javascript, function

i want to write a JavaScript function which finds the difference between  the biggest and the smallest number. Input may be any number, so I use `arguments`.

I wrote a max and a min function, alone they are working fine. I have put them in a difference function to calculate max-min and return the result. 
But there is a bug somewhere, the code is not running as expected.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Finding the difference.</p>
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>

function difference() {
var diff = 0;

function findMax() {
    var i, max = 0;
        for(i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
            if (arguments[i] > max) {
            max = arguments[i];
        }
    }
    return max;
} 

function findMin() {
    var i, min=Infinity;
        for(i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
            if (arguments[i] < min) {
            min = arguments[i];
        }
    }
    return min;
} 
diff=max-min;
return diff;

}

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = difference(4, 5, 6,88);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're not calling the `findMax()` and `findMin()` functions anywhere.

Comment: Also, `var i, max = 0` sould be `var i, max = -Infinity` if you want to handle negative numbers properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If for some reason you wish to make use of your existing `findMin()` and `findMax()` methods, you are only missing the invocation of these methods.

Inside `difference()`, you should do this:

```
var numbers = Array.slice(arguments);   // create an array of args
var max = findMax.apply(this, numbers);
var min = findMin.apply(this, numbers);
return max - min;
```

And do fix your `findMax()` method as suggested by a comment if you wish to handle negative numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead

```
function difference() {
    var i, val = parseFloat(arguments[0]), min = val, max = val;

    for(i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        val = arguments[i];
        min = Math.min(val, min);
        max = Math.max(val, max);
    }
    return max - min;
}
```

no need for infinity either

Comment: I think you should probably check to see if `arguments` is not empty, and also check that the rest of the values in `arguments` are actually numbers.

Answer (score 2):

You never call either `findMin()` or `findMax()`.

You can use the builtins [`Math.min()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min) or [`Math.max()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) instead, they  both take an unlimited number of arguments so you can avoid iterating over the arguments yourself.

Like so:

```
function difference() {
    var min = Math.min.apply(null, arguments),
        max = Math.max.apply(null, arguments);

    return max - min;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in one for loop much easier:

```
var numbers = [4, 8, 1, 100, 50];

function difference(arr) {
    var max = arr[0]
    var min = arr[0];
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 1) {
        if(arr[i] > max) {
            max = arr[i];
        }
        if(arr[i] < min) {
            min = arr[i];
        }
    }
    var d = max - min;
    return d;
}

var result = difference(numbers);
console.log(result);
```